# System.Windows.Media.Imaging for asp.net

Tags: .net, wpf, image, gdi+

There are some very useful classes for working with images. I am stuck with gdi+ for now, I would like to use these classes for my web app. I tried to add a reference but I can't find the assembly.

Any ideas if this is even possible?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are looking to tap into the linked namespace classes, you need to reference "PresentationCore.Dll" in your project.

It should be in the listing under .NET references, and the assembly is usually under

**c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationCore.dll**